# ffmpeg download from m3u8 link but not from local m3u8 file

Tags: ffmpeg, m3u8

I downloaded a master m3u8 from a link and now I want to download by
`ffmpeg -i test.m3u8 -acodec copy -vcodec copy out.mp4`
it to mp4 but now it not downloading
and getting an error `Output file #0 does not contain any stream`
but when I use the link (like https://google.com/master.m3u8) it downloads the video file
`ffmpeg -i https://google.com/master.m3u8 -acodec copy -vcodec copy out.mp4`

I want to download the video using local m3u8 file

PS. my session is not out Vlc still show the VIDEO

Comment: That's because the playlist must contain relative URIs to locate the resources on the remote server. You would have to edit the playlist and put absolute URLs in place, but you would need to do this for each variant playlist. But why bother when you can just use the original link?

Comment: no, it doesn't have relative URLs
@aergistal [img](https://i.imgur.com/dWVfqec.png)

Answer (score 1):

pretty simple answer to this is in the below link

don't worry its not a rickroll...

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-Audio-options

look at section 5.1
topic -map_channel

Hope this helps...

please give a green tick.